# ¿Como guardar cambios en estados de componentes clase en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Buenas estoy realizando este simple componente de clase que tiene que solicitar informacion de una API publica para mostrar una lista de usuarios.

Revise la funcion de `fetchUsers` y funciona perfectamente

[image: ado]

Este es mi componente

```
import React from 'react'
import User from './components/User'
import './main.css'

class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
        data: []
    }

    this.fetchUsers = this.fetchUsers.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUsers()
}

async fetchUsers() {
    console.log('Fetching users...')

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const req = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
        const data = await req.json()
        
        this.setState([{
            name: data.results[0].name.first + ' ' + data.results[0].name.last,
            pic: data.results[0].picture.thumbnail,
            id: data.results[0].login.uuid
        }, ...this.state.data])
    }  
}

render() {
    const { data } = this.state

    return (
        <>
            <header>
                <h1>User List</h1>
            </header>
            <main>
                {
                    data.map(item => {
                        return <User key={item.id} name={item.name} pic={item.pic} job={'Ocupation'} />
                    })
                }
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
}

export default App
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que los datos, no se estan guardando en el estado `data` asi que queria preguntarles como realizas esto usando componentes de clases (no hooks). Cuando pruebo en la pagina no se muestra nada de la lista y cuando imprimo el estado sale que esta vacio.

Comment: Tienes que hacer `this.setState({data:[...this.state.data, {NUEVO,USUARIO}]})`, de lo contrario al hacer el setState estas eliminando la propiedad de `data`

Comment: @FranAcuna porque no lo pusiste como respuesta? te ganabas puntos! muchas gracias